# $find returns null after ajaxRequest()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, find, updatepanel

I have a button outside an update panel, when clicked, calls the following javascript function to fire my updatepanel "pnlDocs":

```
// javascript
function updateRightPane()
{
     $find('<%= pnlDocs.ClientID %>').ajaxRequest();
}
```

I have a control inside an update panel called "rtbFolderDocs" **before** the ajax callback $find will return my object:

```
// javascript
var bar = $find("<%= rtbFolderDocs.ClientID %>"); // bar will have an object
```

But **after** calling "updateRightPane" $find will return null. 
However, $get will return the element. I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

I must be missing something about how partial page refreshing and $find work together.

**Note:** The error occurs if my javascript is inside or outside of my updatepanel.

*Here is a screen shot of my console testing in Google Chrome with $get, $find, $jQuery*
[image]

**Update**
It appears the $find method returns null for ALL objects on my page, not just those in the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The ajax response was causing the $find code to run **before** Sys.Application had finished loading all components.

Once I forced the $find code to run after Sys.Application had finished processing: 
i.e.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(findTheControl);
```

Everything was right with the world again.